# Clickable Phone numbers in Google Docs

Tags: hyperlink, google-docs, phone-call

Is there a way to make phone numbers *clickable* in **Google Docs** similar to **MS Word** [like here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/clickable-phone-numbers-in-word-documents/3ed057a0-789a-47c3-bdbc-f6592e848c4e)?

Please note that this can be done in Google Sheets using:

`=HYPERLINK("tel:1234567890", "Call Me")`

I am asking for Docs.

Thank you.

Comment: does not seem to work on Google Sheets

Comment: @FredericBazin is right, it is not working in Google Sheets. 
Help explains why:
«Only certain link types are allowed. http://, https://, mailto:, aim:, ftp://, gopher://, telnet://, and news:// are permitted; others are explicitly forbidden. If another protocol is specified, link_label will be displayed in the cell, but will not be hyperlinked.»

Comment: Yes, you are right, `=HYPERLINK("tel:1234567890", "Call Me")` doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 12):

Google Docs now supports call/telephone links by adding a hyperlink with `tel` followed by the phone number.

Example

- U.S. - `tel:1234567890`
- Int'l - `tel:+11234567890`

When clicking the link the browser displays a call prompt.

Comment: Google Docs was already supporting this at the time of my question. I'm asking for Sheets.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, there's no direct way of doing this, but you can use Apps Script and deploy a web application that will solve your issue.

You will have to use this script using Apps Script [script editor](https://www.google.com/script/start/):

```js
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<script>window.location.href='tel:" + e.parameter.tel + "';</script>");
}
```

The code contains a `doGet(e)` function which sends an HTTP `GET` request and returns a new `HtmlOutput` object, which has as a parameter the phone number of your choice.

Afterwards, you have to deploy this script as a web application and after that, you will get a URL corresponding to it.

If you want to use it in Google Docs, you can create a link made out of the following link:

`your-web-application-URL+?tel=the-phone-number-you-want` .

Furthermore, here are some links for you that might be of help:

1. [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script);
2. [Google Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web);
3. [HtmlService Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service);
4. [Create a link in Google Docs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/45893?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).

Comment: while the following works on desktop, it does not work on mobile (neither iOS nor Android) :( do you have any idea why, just in case?

Comment: Can you elaborate what to do after you create the web app? I created the script and deployed as a Web App. I got a link to the web app that looks like this: https://script.google.com/a/macros/xyz/exec/

Then I created a hyperlink as follows:
HYPERLINK("https://script.google.com/a/macros/xyz/exec?tel=" &A1, A1)
where A1 is the Googlesheet cell with the phone number.

When I click on the link, I end up with a blank google page.