# How to make a clickable call link in google sheets (for whole column)

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column A with numbers formatted like this `'+49 12345678`
How do I make this clickable?

The obvious [https://spreadsheetpoint.com/phone-number-format-google-sheets/](google solution) is to do it like this `=Hyperlink("https://ctrlq.org/call/ "&A1; "Call me")` which seams to not work for me.

I tried formatting the number in different ways, which also did not work.

Comment: `"https://call.ctrlq.org/call/"` instead of `"https://ctrlq.org/call/ "`

Comment: I tried this. So this is the Formula now: =HYPERLINK("https://call.ctrlq.org/call/"&F2; F2)

And what happens is, interestingly I end up on this website: https://www.labnol.org/internet/google-sheets-phone-numbers/29228/

But our VOIP Dialer does not open.

Comment: `Only certain link types are allowed. http://, https://, mailto:, aim:, ftp://, gopher://, telnet://, and news:// are permitted; others are explicitly forbidden. If another protocol is specified, link_label will be displayed in the cell, but will not be hyperlinked.` You'll notice that `tel` is not included.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clickable Phone numbers in Google Docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59058493/clickable-phone-numbers-in-google-docs)